# getline() Adding Character to Front of String? -- Actually substr syntax error

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I'm writing a program that will balance Chemistry Equations; I thought it'd be a good challenge and help reinforce the information I've recently learned.

My program is set up to use `getline(cin, std::string)` to receive the equation. From there it separates the equation into two halves: a left side and right side by making a substring when it encounters a `=`.

I'm having issues which only concerns the left side of my string, which is called `std::string leftSide`. My program then goes into a for loop that iterates over the length of `leftSide`. The first condition checks to see if the character is uppercase, because chemical formulas are written with the element symbols and a symbol consists of either one upper case letter, or an upper case and one lower case letter. After it checks to see if the current character is uppercase, it checks to see if the next character is lower case; if it's lower case then I create a temporary string, combine `leftSide[index]` with `leftSide[index+1]` in the temp string then push the string to my vector.

My problem lies on the first iteration; I've been using CuFe3 = 8 (right side doesn't matter right now) to test it out. The only thing stored in `std::string temp` is `C`. I'm not sure why this happening; also, I'm still getting numbers in my final answer and I don't understand why. Some help fixing these two issues, along with an explanation, would be greatly appreciated.

**[CODE]**

```
int index = 0;
    for (it = leftSide.begin(); it!=leftSide.end(); ++it, index++)
    {
        bool UPPER_LETTER = isupper(leftSide[index]);
        bool NEXT_LOWER_LETTER = islower(leftSide[index+1]);
        if (UPPER_LETTER)// if the character is an uppercase letter
        {
            if (NEXT_LOWER_LETTER)
            {
                string temp = leftSide.substr(index, (index+1));//add THIS capital and next lowercase
                elementSymbol.push_back(temp); // add temp to vector
                temp.clear(); //used to try and fix problem initially
            }

            else if (UPPER_LETTER && !NEXT_LOWER_LETTER) //used to try and prevent number from getting in
            {
                string temp = leftSide.substr(index, index);
                elementSymbol.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        else if (isdigit(leftSide[index])) // if it's a number
            num++;

    }
```

***[EDIT]*** When I entered in only `ASDF`, `*** ***S ***DF ***F` was the output.

Comment: The signature of substr is `string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;` Hence pass the first index and the amount of characters.

Comment: Also, you don't have to use an Iterator in the for loop if you don't use it within. for(size_t index = 0; index < leftSide.size(); ++index) works just fine.

Comment: @dieterlucking I didn't realize that. I'll correct that once I can get on my computer. I'm still really new to C++ and I just learned about `substr` yesterday and followed a tutorial.

Comment: Am I still able to to use index for the index of the string if it's `size_t`?

Comment: Yes, you should still be able to use it (but you'd get a warning I believe).

Comment: Also I'd suggest not using all uppercase variable names, it suggests that they are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> string temp = leftSide.substr(index, (index+1));
> ```

substr takes the first index and then a length, rather than first and last indices. You want `substr(index, 2)`. Since in your example `index` is 0 you're doing: `substr(index, 1)` which creates a string of length 1, which is `"C"`.

> ```
> string temp = leftSide.substr(index, index);
> ```

Since `index` is 0 this is `substr(index, 0)`, which creates a string of length 0, that is, an empty string.

When you're processing parts of the string with a higher index, such as `Fe` in `"CuFe3"` the value you pass in as the length parameter is higher and so you're creating strings that are longer. `F` is at index 2 and you call `substr(index, 3)`, which creates the string `"Fe3"`.

<sub>Also the standard library usually uses half open ranges, so even if substr took two indices (which, again, it doesn't) you would do `substr(index, index+2)` to get a two character string.</sub>

> ```
> bool NEXT_LOWER_LETTER = islower(leftSide[index+1]);
> ```

You might want to check that `index+1` is a valid index. If you don't want to do that manually you might at least switch to using the bounds checked function `at()` instead of `operator[]`.

Comment: Thanks. So, should it be `2` or `index+2`? I switched to `2` in my code, but the antivirus at my school doesnt' allow me to build applications.

Comment: @Crysis The comment about `index+2` was just in general about the standard library's use of half-open ranges. `substr()` doesn't actually take two indices so it doesn't apply literally to `substr()`. `substr(index, 2)` is the only correct way.

Comment: I'll probably write my own function for the `substr` and indices.

Comment: @Crysis Well, in this case using a length instead of an end position is actually more convenient. If you actually run into a case where an end position is more convenient then I'd say go for it.

Comment: True. A symbol is going to be a max of two characters.